# Conversion byte[ ] to String returns <���� working on android bluetooth low energy

Tags: android

none of the `charsets` is working.

```java
public void onCharacteristicChanged(byte[] data){
Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged: " + new String(data,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the device is writing string data into the characteristics you are reading from?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i am using BLE simulator cause i don't have bluetooth peripherals at the moment. Is there any way to check if simulator is writing string data? thanks

Comment: who decides which data it is writing? Isn't it you?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have figured out that the data from characteristic is inconvertible . Thanks